# Regex - Match Words which are not Strings

Tags: regex, kotlin

I am trying to distinguish between words and strings. I managed to get strings working, but I can't quite figure out how to only match words which are not surrounded by double quotes:

So I want this to match:

```
test
```

But this shouldn't match:

```
"test"
```

This is what I have so far:

```
[^\"][a-zA-Z]*[^\"]
```

It still gets the test although it is surrounded by double quotes.

```
Input: "\"this is a string\" word"
Expected Output: word
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am using Kotlin. It works fine if I type it into a regex website, but not in Kotlin :/

Comment: Try the regex provided by @LukStorms without escaping the double-quotes. `(?<!")\b[a-zA-Z]+\b(?!")`

Comment: Try `Regex("(?<!\")(?>\\p{L}\\p{M}*+)++(?!\")")`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, your solution works awesome!

Comment: The problem I found is when for example there is a string like this: "seperate this string", it still gets "eperate" and "this". But there is no way to avoid it, is there? (Btw: It would be okay if it would only recognize words which are all upper case)

Comment: please describe your intention more clearly.

Comment: Lets say I want to lex this whole string for strings and words:

"\"this should be a string\" these are seperated words"

The problem I am encountering is that with the above regex by Wiktor, it recognizes the seperate components inside of the string as words as well. Do you think it is a better idea to go thorugh manual lexing instead of using RegEx in this case?

Comment: @Rechunk thanks, wait for a moment.

Comment: The more appropriate approach is to match what you do not need, and match and capture what you need.  `"\"[^\"]*\"|((?>\\p{L}\\p{M}*+)+)"`. Could you please share your current testing code? You will need to access Group 1 value.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I actually haven't written any testing code, yet. Shame on me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about it?

```
assert("\"<quoted>\" word".words == listOf("word"))

assert("head \"<quoted>\" word".words == listOf("head", "word"))

assert("head\"<quoted>\"word".words == listOf("head", "word"))

assert("\"<escaped\\\"quoted>\"".words == emptyList())

assert("; punctuations , ".words == listOf("punctuations"))
```

---

```
inline val String.words get() = dropStrings().split("[^\\p{Alpha}]+".toRegex())
                                             .filter { it.isNotBlank() }

@Suppress("NOTHING_TO_INLINE")
inline fun String.dropStrings() = replace("\"(\\[\"]|.*)?\"".toRegex(), " ")
```

Comment: Wow, perfect solution! Thank you a lot! Could you maybe explain to me how it roughly works?

Comment: @Rechunk Not at all.

Comment: NOTE: This solution will not work in several scenarios: 1) if the words are separated with punctuation, 2) if the double quoted strings may contain escaped double quotes that should be ignored, 3) if there are compound hyphenated words.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sir, keep it simple just now.  there is no need to make the things complex, if the input never contains punctuations, escaped chars.  if it is too complex, I'd like to use a grammar rather than a regex.

Comment: @Rechunk I'm sorry, I didn't see your comment clearly. How about it now? the code is **self-describing** after refactoring.